# Weblogic and Spring JMS configuration throws java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, weblogic, spring-jms

Converting EJB MDB application to Spring base JMS service.

JMS Queue configuration is in Weblogic server.

Have following in configuration in applicationContext XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">


    <bean id="vTMessageQueueListener" class="com.collection.mom.sink.EventMessageBean" />

    <bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>/jms/FilingTopicConnFact</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
        class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="cache">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="QueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="queueConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="destinationResolver">
            <ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="SMMessageQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <!--<property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>-->
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>com/vx/jms/vTMessageQueue</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="V3JMSlistener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" ref="SMMessageQueue"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="vTMessageQueueListener" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

.

```
<HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'V3JMSlistener' defined in class path resource [SpringJMSContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'destinationName'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'destinationName': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'V3JMSlistener' defined in class path resource [SpringJMSContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'destinationName'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'destinationName': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'destinationName'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'destinationName': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1653)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'destinationName': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: So, at what point do you see this exception?  ie What do you have to do to cause it?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<property name="destination" ref="SMMessageQueue"/>
```

instead of `destinationName`.

Spring can resolve a destination from its name but since you have the destination, you should inject that directly.